# ACS Australia Skill Assessment: does relevant work experience during bachelor studies count?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, australia

Imagine the situation:
Let's say I obtained my Computer Science Bachelor degree in June 2017 (I was a full-time student).
During my studies I started working as a full-time (30 h/w) researcher in an international company officially. That was since May 2016.
So, by June 2018, I will already have a CS Bachelor degree AND two years of relevant full-time work experience.
Does it mean that I can apply now?

The reference on ACS website gives only an example of sequential study and work experience. But it says nothing about my case.
Could you please provide me with a link to an official answer to the question?

Comment: I’d imagine the defining point in time is when you formally gained the qualification

Comment: Have you discovered anything about this? I have the same question.

Comment: No, sorry, not yet. Postponed it until I try applying next year and find out :) I would be more than grateful if you let me know about updates on the case. lera-bubnova@yandex.ru

Answer (score 2):

I'm modifying my answer based on the very helpful information pointed out by the OP.

Work in the field you're applying for and that you want to count as skilled employment (for points), must be done after you have met your "skill level requirement met" date. That date is determined by when you have finished two years of suitable work experience and some sort of tertiary education or certificate.

See page 5 of the [Skills Assessment Guidelines](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20V5-6%20Aug%202018.pdf).

> The Skill Level Requirement Met Date will be noted on your ACS result letter and will be determined by the outcome of the suitability criteria.
>
> All relevant work experience completed after the Skill Level Requirement Met Date will be considered Skilled Employment and eligible for points under the skilled migration points test.
>
> The work experience required to meet the suitability criteria is NOT included as Skilled Employment and is NOT eligible for points under the skilled migration points test. (Note from me: This sentence is about internships etc. required by the degree program)

One example in the document shows the suitable employment occurring before the educational requirement. The OP has 1 year suitable employment occurring concurrently with a year of education, then 1 year post-graduation.

My guess is that the current employment would count but I don't know for sure. I suggest contacting Australian immigration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I should have mentioned, that I do not mean work experience to gain points. I only ask about work experience needed to confirm your qualifications. In particular, if you study outside Australia, in order to meet requirements, you have to not only obtain a degree, but also work for 2 years in the same field. That is experience I am asking about: what Skilled Level Requirement Met Date will be in my case?

Comment: You can't use a computer science-related job as work experience until after you have the bachelor's degree. You hadn't met the skill level requirement yet for the job you did while pursuing the degree.

Comment: Yes, but in order to meet the requirements, I have to provide evidence of work for 2 years. Without that my Bachelor is simply not sufficient for me to meet the requirements. Please, see example 2 here (p.5): https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20V5-6%20Aug%202018.pdf. There the experience to gain qualification is BEFORE Bachelors. And I want to do it during Bachelors. That is was the question is about: is it possible?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that example out. I had missed the difference between skilled employment and 2 years needed for suitability/skill level requirement met. Hmmm. Because applying is  expensive, I would contact Australian immigration and ask them.

Comment: Unfortunately, they wouldn’t answer the question directly. “To determine whether a suitable outcome will be provide this what a formal assessment is for.” (citation) - is what they answered me. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Ugh. I'm sorry.